# Menu items don't show on large screens (pure.css)

Tags: css-frameworks

This is pure.css framework (https://purecss.io/). I'm trying to copy a menu from their examples.

Documentation (and a working example): https://purecss.io/layouts/tucked-menu-vertical/

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.3/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-cg6SkqEOCV1NbJoCu11+bm0NvBRc8IYLRGXkmNrqUBfTjmMYwNKPWBTIKyw9mHNJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/custom.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="custom-wrapper pure-g" id="menu">
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <div class="pure-menu">
                <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading custom-brand">Brand</a>
                <a href="#" class="custom-toggle" id="toggle"><s class="bar"></s><s class="bar"></s></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal custom-can-transform">
                <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal custom-menu-3 custom-can-transform">
                <ul class="pure-menu-list">
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Yahoo</a></li>
                    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">W3C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
.custom-wrapper {
  background-color: #ffd390;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  height: 2.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

.custom-wrapper.open {
  height: 14em;
}

.custom-menu-3 {
  text-align: right;
}

.custom-toggle {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.custom-toggle .bar {
  background-color: #777;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.custom-toggle .bar:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.custom-toggle.x .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.custom-toggle.x .bar:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media (max-width: 47.999em) {
  .custom-menu-3 {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .custom-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=custom.css.map */
```

**JS**

```
  (function (window, document) {
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
      rollback,
      WINDOW_CHANGE_EVENT = ('onorientationchange' in window) ? 'orientationchange':'resize';

  function toggleHorizontal() {
      menu.classList.remove('closing');
      [].forEach.call(
          document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('.custom-can-transform'),
          function(el){
              el.classList.toggle('pure-menu-horizontal');
          }
      );
  };

  function toggleMenu() {
      // set timeout so that the panel has a chance to roll up
      // before the menu switches states
      if (menu.classList.contains('open')) {
          menu.classList.add('closing');
          rollBack = setTimeout(toggleHorizontal, 500);
      }
      else {
          if (menu.classList.contains('closing')) {
              clearTimeout(rollBack);
          } else {
              toggleHorizontal();
          }
      }
      menu.classList.toggle('open');
      document.getElementById('toggle').classList.toggle('x');
  };

  function closeMenu() {
      if (menu.classList.contains('open')) {
          toggleMenu();
      }
  }

  document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      toggleMenu();
      e.preventDefault();
  });

  window.addEventListener(WINDOW_CHANGE_EVENT, closeMenu);
  })(this, this.document);
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Kifsif/pen/xxwMQpd

The problem is that menu items on large screens are not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` property from custom-wrapper class and it will be shown. Although I am not sure if menu on large screen is positioned well but that is another problem.

```
.custom-wrapper {
      background-color: #ffd390;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      height: 2.1em;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
      transition: height 0.5s;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to fix position you can not just hide it. Menu items on large screens are not shown, that was your problem and they were hidden because overflow property.